# how to pass json from two query in single array

Tags: mysql, arrays, database

$sql = "SELECT user_registration.user_id, user_registration.full_name, user_registration.username, user_profile.profile_picture FROM user_registration LEFT JOIN user_profile ON user_registration.user_id = user_profile.user_id ";

```
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $outaa[] = $row;

            $f_user_id = $row['user_id'];

        $sql1 = "SELECT status FROM user_follower WHERE (from_user_id = '$f_user_id' AND to_user_id = '$user_id' ) OR (from_user_id = '$user_id' AND to_user_id = '$f_user_id' )";

        $result1 = $con->query($sql1);
        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

            $outaa[] = $row1;
        } 
        }
        else {
            $outaa[] =  "No";
        }   

    }
    }
   $out = array_merge(array('result'=>'true','reason'=>'Data Fetching Succesfully','user_suggested_data' => $outaa));
```

i wanted to pass in single array.

Ans like :

"user_suggested_data": {
        "0": {
            "user_id": "121",
            "full_name": "Ankit Shah",
            "username": "shah_ankit39",
            "profile_picture": null,
            "status": 0 
        },
        "1": {
            "user_id": "122",
            "full_name": "pooja",
            "username": "pooja25",
            "profile_picture": null,
            "status": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "user_id": "123",
            "full_name": "swapnil",
            "username": "swapnil25",
            "profile_picture": null,
            "status": 0 
        },

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by improving your SQL query to:

```
  SELECT
    user_registration.user_id,
    user_registration.full_name,
    user_registration.username,
    user_profile.profile_picture,
    user_follower.status
  FROM
    user_registration LEFT JOIN user_profile USING(user_id)
  WHERE
    (user_follower.to_user_id = '$user_id'
      AND user_follower.from_user_id = user_registration.user_id)
    OR (user_follower.from_user_id = '$user_id'
      AND user_follower.to_user_id = user_registration.user_id)"
```

store it as a string in `$sql` variable and finally, perform the query:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
```